# Recurrent dropout in GRU layer increase farily loss value

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using Keras to predict the temperature using the Jena climate dataset and using a GRU layer. When I set `recurrent_dropout` on a value to be more than 0.1, the accuracy of the program drops significantly and after a few rounds it becomes `NaN` even though the dropout value is not large. The same model without a `recurrent_dropout` works just fine.

As part of my learning, I'm copying pieces of code from my reference book, and I don't expect to run into huge problems. Here is the code I'm working on, and I don't understand where the problem is.

```py
mean = float_data[:200000].mean(axis = 0)
float_data -= mean

std = float_data[:200000].std(axis = 0)
float_data /= std

model = Sequential()
model.add(layers.GRU(32, dropout = 0.2, recurrent_dropout = 0.2, input_shape = (None, float_data.shape[-1])))
model.add(layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer = RMSprop(), loss = 'mae')
history = model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch = 500, epochs = 40, validation_data = val_gen, validation_steps = val_steps)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recurrent dropout is applied every timestep of the sequence. So for example, if the (recurrent) dropout rate was .1, and you were passing a sequence of length 100 through the recurrence, then the probability of any recurrent unit still being active at the end of the sequence is (.9^100) = 1/37600.